# Manual Acknowledgement (Checkpointing) of Messages: Spring Cloud Stream Kenesis Binder

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

We are trying to port our Spring Cloud Stream application which consumes messages from Kafka to AWS Kenesis. We require manual acknowledgement for handling certain timeout conditions.

For Kafka we use property `autocommitoffset` to false and use the ACKNOWLEDGEMENT header to handle the manual acknowledgement.

I went through the documentation for Spring Cloud Stream
went through the below:
https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/kinesis/simple-producer-consumer/
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc

But could not find any solutions.  Any pointers would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching, found the solution :

In Kenesis the  `shard` is equivalent to `partition` and `checkpoint` to `offset`

In Application Yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kinesis:
        bindings:
          consumer-in-0:
            consumer:
              checkpointMode: manual
```

Sample Code for checkpointing

```
 @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<String>> consume() {
        return message -> {
            System.out.println("message received : "+ message.getPayload());
            System.out.println("message headers : "+ message.getHeaders());
            Checkpointer checkPointer = (Checkpointer) message.getHeaders().get(AwsHeaders.CHECKPOINTER);
            checkPointer.checkpoint();
           
        };
    }
```

Referred
[Kenesis Consumer Binder Properties](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#kinesis-consumer-properties)

Comment: See here for more info: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/#amazon-kinesis